# Record Page Greyed out , due to LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-record-page

There is a LWC component from Managed Package which is added to a Lightning Record Page.
This LWC component takes time to load , as there are huge number of records to be retrieved.
But Until the LWC component is loaded , the whole Record Page is greyed out , which shouldn't be the case.
What could be the reason for this and what can be done to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

A modal backdrop using the SLDS CSS classes `slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open` is designed to do this - see [Modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/). And when used appropriately this is a good thing.

It sounds like the LWC that has been developed by the managed package supplier  is not designed to handle the volume of data you have well. (Or has a bug that gets in the way.) You should contact the managed package supplier and raise your issue with them as they are the only people who can offer good advice or perhaps improve/fix the component.

Meanshile, remove that LWC from your pages.